# MySQL deactivated in Lampp, Xampp on Linux 12.04

Tags: mysql, linux, apache2, xampp, lampp

I have freshly installed xampp-linux-1.8.1 on my Ubuntu 12.04 (Mint 13 maya) Operating system.
When run lampp, I get :

```
/opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: XAMPP-Apache is already running.
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started.
```

In the : localhost/xampp/
MySQL DataBase is Deactivated !!!

```
ps -aux | grep 'mysql'
Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html     mysql     3159  0.0  0.9 316264 31880 ?        Ssl  16:48   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      4745  0.0  0.0   4648   840 pts/5    S+   17:02   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

When I tried to stop /usr/sbin/mysqld but it can't be stopped with this command !!!

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld stop
```

Please I need Help, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've resolved the issue in this way:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp
sudo chown -hR nobody /opt/lampp
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp
```

then stop other mysqld running with:

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Also had this issue, after troubleshooting for almost 2 hours I found that it was because of other Apache and MySQL packages also running on my system. Removed all Apache and MySQL packages and reinstalled XAMPP again. Success.