# Restarted my pc and suddenly MySQL deactivated in xampp(lampp) on Linux 12.04

Tags: mysql, linux, apache, ubuntu, xampp

It was all working fine for a long time i don't even remember when i installed this Ubuntu on my pc it was more than 6 months for sure.

And i have xampp (it's called lampp) on Linux setup and all was working fine, until suddenly now from last restart i can't run MySQL

When i try to go to localhost/phpmyadmin im getting error

```
#2002 - No such file or directory
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

When i check localhost/xampp under status it says

```
    MySQL database   DEACTIVATED
```

when i try to restart it i get this

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-2...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...ok.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...ok.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...ok.
```

But still MySQL not working when i do restart again i get same response. When i try to start/stop just mysql i get this

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp startmysql
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stopmysql
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...not running.
```

No matter how many times i try to start it it wont start.

/etc/init.d/mysql or service mysql is not installad and it shouldn't be when using xampp

I tried this [MySQL deactivated in Lampp, Xampp on Linux 12.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187687/mysql-deactivated-in-lampp-xampp-on-linux-12-04) and this [Couldn't start MySQL! while starting XAMPP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507358/couldnt-start-mysql-while-starting-xampp) and other answers but no luck

I checked all the logs i could find in /opt/lampp folder but no luck. I checked php.ini httpd mysql config and i don't see anything wrong, all the users permissions and passwords are right.

So any help, what could be the problem so it just stops working when i didn't touched anything just restarted my pc.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same thing after I dumbly executed restart command to my entire xampp applications, causing my database to shutdown unexpectedly and crashed the mysql application.

I found this [link](http://www.softaculous.com/board/index.php?tid=5375&title=MySQL_won%27t_start_-_please_help%3F) and followed his solution.

In summary what I did was, in my.cnf, search for this:

```
[mysqld]
```

w/c for my case is located at ***/opt/lampp/etc/my.cnf***
and directly below that, on a new line, put this:

```
innodb_force_recovery = 1
```

Then I **properly** restarted my lampp applications using

```
/opt/lampp/lampp/ stop
```

and then

```
/opt/lampp/lampp/ start
```

Then I check using the

```
/opt/lampp/lampp/ status
```

and saw my MySQL is now running

then I revert back the **innodb_force_recovery value from 1 to 0**.

Comment: Thank you! In Ubuntu 16 I had same problem. Yes I add line 'innodb_force_recovery = 1' after 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50'

Answer (score 0):

Alright after loosing all night on trying to fix and looking at logs i finally found an .err file inside mysql databases folder.

The .err file lead to some sort of errors while reading some of the database files, apparently they got corrupted somehow and mysql was not able to read them thus stoping execution and crashed. So i deleted that few files of databases and mysql is running again.